# To prove rectangles contained by circle segments are constant

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, polar-coordinates

If from a fixed point, a straight line is drawn to cut a given circle, then how would I show that the rectangle contained by the segments is constant? 
*(I can't form a good sketch of the figure required for this. And I can't figure out how to even begin)*

Comment: The property you're looking for (the area of any of these possible rectangles) is called the [power of that fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to the circle.

Comment: @Arthur How is that related to the rectangles? i still don't get it. How i see the diagram in my head is a point sending one line cutting through a circle at 2 points. There is a rectangle inscribed in each segment and i have to prove that they remain constant. Am i interpreting the question wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are. If your point is $P$ and the line intersects the circle at $I$ and $J$, then $PI$ is one segment and $PJ$ is the other. They are talking about a rectangle with two sides congruent to $PI$ and two sides congruent to $PJ$. Which is to say, $|PI|\cdot |PJ|$ remains constant regardless of where you draw the line. However, I wouldn't personally use the rectangle in any actual proof. It is too far removed from the relationship between the point, the line and the circle to be of any actual use. It's just part of an unnecessarily archaic way of describing the product of two lengths.